# Can i detect if a user canceled navigation from Google Maps App

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, proximity

My app calls an `Intent` to open the Google Maps App like so

```
Intent navigation = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+trueFriend.lat+","+trueFriend.lon));
startActivity(navigation);
```

When i do that i would like to set a ProximityListener to detect if the user has arrived to there location, then let the other user know that they have arrived. That much i can do, however in order to prevent a few issues i need to detect if a user has canceled there navigation, or stopped, or possibly even resumed. Is there any documentation to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you are in another app so there is no way of knowing if the user has canceled the navigation from the google maps app.

**Edit**

something you could possibly do but would only work on 4.3 would be to set a `notification listener` and check to see if the navigation notification still exists, if it doesnt then they quit it.

this would be very hacky and I dont even know if it would work but its an idea i guess

Comment: Hmmm... that sucks. Okay so another question, the Google Maps API V2 for Android states that it embeds their google maps app into a fragment which is inside my app. If i do that will that support the turn by turn directions? Or no? If not, are there any open source map api's that do?

Comment: No for both, the only thing you can do is use google directions API which gives you directions to you destination up to 2500 requests/day but then you have to manage all the plotting, speaking and everything else

Comment: Thats a bummer... Thanks.