# How to implement GoogleMap.CancelableCallback

Tags: android, google-maps, callback, android-navigation

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.CancelableCallback) don't explain much on how to use `GoogleMap.CancelableCallback`. Can I use it to notify my app that navigation has been cancelled using this callback? Can someone give me an example? Since the navigation is a separate app I learned it is hard to know if the user has cancelled the navigation or finished the navigation based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143598/can-i-detect-if-a-user-canceled-navigation-from-google-maps-app) but there is gotta be a way because Uber driver app has the ability to cancel the trip based on the passenger's request. I am very frustrated at this question, please help is badly needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GoogleMap.CancelableCallback` notifies you when a map task has successfully completed or it has been cancelled by the user.

In a `GoogleMap`, you can attach this callback to the `animateCamera` ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#animateCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate,%20int,%20com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.CancelableCallback))) to know if the user has cancelled the `animateCamera` task.

You can implement it like this:

```
map.animateCamera(yourCameraUpdate, new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // Code to execute when the animateCamera task has finished
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // Code to execute when the user has canceled the animateCamera task
    }
});
```

As you see, this callback doesn't provide the functionality you are looking for, and as [Can i detect if a user canceled navigation from Google Maps App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143598/can-i-detect-if-a-user-canceled-navigation-from-google-maps-app) says, if you use Google Maps to perform your navigation, since Google Maps is a different app there is no way you can know if the user has canceled the navigation.

As @tyczj states in the comments of [Can i detect if a user canceled navigation from Google Maps App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143598/can-i-detect-if-a-user-canceled-navigation-from-google-maps-app), you can use Google Directions API taking into account the [usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-limits).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use it for navigation, since you call navigation as an extra intent of you call, and not as part of your code.
That callback is for animation cancel:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#animateCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate, com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.CancelableCallback)

you call

```
myMap.animateCamera(ANIMATION_UPDATEPARAMS,GoogleMap.CancelableCallback{...});
```

so I don't think you can. I'm not aware of how Uber does things, but I don't think it launches google maps and understand when and if navigation changes...